# How to mount volume from my container in kubenetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to mount directory from SourceContaner to ServerContainer.

ServerContainer:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite
# /var/www/html is apache document root.
```

SourceContaner:

```
FROM alpine:3.7

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY ./my_src /var/www/html/my_src
VOLUME /var/www/html/my_src
```

And, yaml is below.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
spec:

...snip...

    spec:
      containers:
      - name: server-container
        image: "Server Container image"
        ports:
          ...snip...

        volumeMounts:
          - name: src-volume
            mountPath: /var/www/html/my_src
      - name: src-container
        image: "Source Container Image"
      volumes:
        - name: src-volume
          hostPath:
            path: /var/www/html/my_src
```

But Source Container "CrashLoopBackOff" occured.
and nothing log is output.

Comment: Did you try to describe the pod that was failing? What was the error message? 

Also, you can't mount a path from inside a container to another container. You should use a PersistentVolume and mount that in both containers where you want to use that using a RWX AccessMode (if that is allowed).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using Kubernetes this way: you need to make sure you've copied the application code to _every_ node on the cluster, and repeat that manual push every time you have a change, which kind of defeats the point.  Does that image work on a plain Docker environment, with no bind mounts?  I'd try debugging that setup first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a feature of Kubernetes. There is an old FlexVolume plugin that implements the same behavior as Docker, but it isn’t recommended. You can use an initContainer to copy from the data container into a volume like an emptyDir.